# Using ScrollPath jQuery plugin, any way to pause scrolling when it hits a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery ScrollPath plugin, and I was wondering if their was a way to get the path to stop at each DIV for a second or so. I've seen other plugins do things like that.

I've seen it on other sites, where you keep scrolling, and it halts the scrolling for a second or so.

Here is the site I am using it on:

http://mikelegacywebdesign.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing using jQuery Scrollpath plugin and I found a workaround way to do it, though I realise that it might not be the best way to do so.

I modified the source code of the plugin at the `scrollToStep()` function which is basically responsible for the actual scrolling and added a conditional check based on a flag variable in the document which when set `true` escapes the `scrollToStep()` method. Now by simply setting the flag using some external code of your choice through suitably handled `setTimeout()` calls, it's possible to simulate the pause at key-points in the scrollPath.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwatts1980/ghXJG/) with a simple delayed scroll example. I'm not sure how this would interact with the ScrollPath plugin, but it may be a good start.

Comment: That is on an animation, which is useful, but I don't think in my case. I need a delay on a physical scroll from the user. I don't think .delay will work. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: Ok. I thought you wanted to run through the page automatically. If you intentionally ignore a scroll by the user (even for a short period of time), that could be a bit confusing for them. Seems like they'd wonder what happened to their mouse or the site or something.